# Grails 2.3 - [Error] No module found with name

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have put `<g:javascript library="bootstrap.js" />` into my `index.gsp`

My `ApplicationResources.groovy`:

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/bootstrap.js'
    }
}
```

However I get the error:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR [/testApplication].[gsp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/testApplication] threw exception
Message: Error mapping onto view [/index]: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:javascript>: No module found with name [bootstrap.js]
    Line | Method
->>   53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:javascript>: No module found with name [bootstrap.js]
->>  530 | doFilter  in C:\Users\user\GrailsWorkspace\testApplication\grails-app\views\index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:javascript>: No module found with name [bootstrap.js]
->>  150 | doCall    in C:/Users/user/GrailsWorkspace/testApplication/grails-app/views/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: No module found with name [bootstrap.js]
->> 1032 | getAllModuleNamesRequired in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1091 | addModuleDispositionsToRequest in     ''
|    144 | declareModuleRequiredByPage in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib
|    330 | doCall    in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib$_closure5_closure20
|    326 | doCall .  in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib$_closure5
|    150 | doCall    in C__Users_user_GrailsWorkspace_testApplication_grails_app_views_index_gsp$_run_closure2
|    152 | run . . . in C__Users_user_GrailsWorkspace_testApplication_grails_app_views_index_gsp
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I also tried `grails clean`. However it does not change my output.

I really appreciate your answer to my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note you have put it under application

```
 application {
        resource url:'js/bootstrap.js'
    }

<g:javascript library="application"/>
```

Should work

Alternatively put this in your ApplicationResource.groovy

```
mydef {
            resource url:'js/bootstrap.js'
        }
```

and this in your gsp page (or main layout page)

```
<g:javascript library="mydef"/>
```